# Callbacks using methods in CODESYS v3

Tags: pointers, callback, twincat, codesys

** TLDR; Is it possible to create pointers to methods, store them and then call them? **

This question is related to this question: [how to create pointer to function in codesys v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43139073/how-to-create-pointer-to-function-in-codesys-v3), but my question is about methods, and, since the referenced question is +5 years old, other solutions might be at hand.

The code below does not work, but it gives an impression of what I am trying to do, and how I expected it to work.

Let's say I have an FB/class: `Alarm`, in which I want to inject a call-back into `Alarm.ActivateCallback` that is to be executed upon activation of the alarm, using `Alarm.Activate()`. PLC_PRG has an instance of the `Alarm` and wants to inject a method `PRG.OnAlarm1Activated()` as the call-back, that, for now, just sets a bool of the PRG to TRUE:

#### FB Alarm

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK Alarm
VAR_INPUT
    ActivateCallback : POINTER TO CallbackDelegate;
END_VAR
```

##### Alarm.Activate()

```
IF (ActivateCallback <> 0) THEN
    ActivateCallback^();
END_IF;
```

#### PLC_PRG:

```
PROGRAM PLC_PRG
VAR
    _init : BOOL := TRUE;   
    _activate : BOOL := FALSE;
    _alarm1 : Alarm;
    _alarm1Activated : BOOL;
END_VAR
```

```
IF (_init) THEN
    _alarm1.ActivateCallback :=ADR(OnAlarm1Activated);
    _init := FALSE;
END_IF


IF (_activate) THEN
    _alarm1.Activate();
END_IF
```

##### PLC_PRG.OnAlarm1Activated():

```
Alarm1Activated := TRUE;
```

For the code above, I get the following errors:

- 'CallbackDelegate' is of type FUNCTION and cannot be instantiated
- Operation 'Adr' is not possible on 'OnAlarm1Activated'

*Can the code above be modified to enable the desired functionality?*

As an alternative, I can use interfaces and inject these. But I would also like to know whether the above is possible as well.

**Side-note**: CODESYS help states the following, but maybe there is a work-around:

> ... CODESYS offers no possibility to call a function pointer within an application in the programming system! ...

#### EDIT to ellaborate more on the interface alternative (excuse my C#/CODESYS hybrid semi-code)

```
public enum AlarmEvent
{
    Activated,
    Cleared,
}

public FB Alarm 
{
    public AlarmHandler : REFERENCE TO IAlarmEventHandler;

    public Activate() {
        AlarmHandler.HandleAlarmEvent(this, AlarmEvent.Activate);
    }
} 

public interface IAlarmEventHandler
{
    public void HandleAlarmEvent(ref Alarm alarm, AlarmEvent event);
}

public FB PLC_PRG : IAlarmEventHandler 
{ 
    Alarm1 : Alarm;

    public FB_Init() {
        Alarm1.AlarmHandler := this;
    }

    public void HandleAlarmEvent(ref Alarm alarm, AlarmEvent event) {
        if (alarm == Alarm1 && event == AlarmEvent.Activated)
            _alarm1Activated = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to inject a FunctionBlock, which is essentially a class, you can use an [Interface](https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.17.0/en/_cds_obj_interface/).

> CODESYS always treats variables declared with the type of an interface as references.

If you want to use a [pointer to a normal function](https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.15.0/en/_cds_datatype_pointer/) however,

> CODESYS does not provide any means for calling a function pointer from within an application in the development system.

So executing a callback function from within an object is not possible.

You'd have to either wrap the function call inside a FunctionBlock and pass it as an Interface:

```pascal
INTERFACE ICallback
    METHOD Invoke;
END_INTERFACE;

FUNCTION_BLOCK CallbackExecutor1 IMPLEMENTS ICallback
    METHOD Invoke
        MyCallbackFunction(); // the function execution is hardcoded
    END_METHOD;
END_FUNCTION_BLOCK;

FUNCTION_BLOCK CallbackExecutor2 IMPLEMENTS ICallback
    METHOD Invoke
        MyProgram.MyCallbackMethod(); // the method execution is hardcoded
    END_METHOD;
END_FUNCTION_BLOCK;

FUNCTION_BLOCK CallbackExecutor3 IMPLEMENTS ICallback
VAR
    _fbRef: REFERENCE TO MyFB;
END_VAR

    METHOD FB_Init: BOOL // constructor
    VAR_INPUT
        bInitRetains: BOOL;
        bInCopyCode: BOOL;
        
        fb_reference: REFERENCE TO MyFB; // to call a method of a FunctionBlock, you need a reference/pointer to an instance of the said FunctionBlock
    END_VAR
    
        _fbRef REF= fb_reference;
    END_METHOD;

    METHOD Invoke
        _fbRef.MyCallbackMethod(); // the method execution is hardcoded
    END_METHOD;
END_FUNCTION_BLOCK;

FUNCTION_BLOCK FB
VAR
    _callback1: ICallback;
    _callback2: ICallback;
    _callback3: ICallback;
END_VAR

    _callback1.Invoke(); // invoke/activate/call where needed
    
    IF TRUE THEN
        _callback2.Invoke(); // invoke/activate/call where needed
    END_IF;
    
    IF FALSE THEN
        _callback3.Invoke(); // invoke/activate/call where needed
    END_IF;

    METHOD FB_Init: BOOL // constructor
    VAR_INPUT
        bInitRetains: BOOL;
        bInCopyCode: BOOL;
        
        callback1: ICallback; // pass callbacks in the constructor
        callback2: ICallback; // pass callbacks in the constructor
        callback3: ICallback; // pass callbacks in the constructor
    END_VAR
    
        _callback1 := callback1;
        _callback2 := callback2;
        _callback3 := callback2;
    END_METHOD;
END_FUNCTION_BLOCK;

PROGRAM Main_07
VAR
    _myfb: MyFB;
    callback1: CallbackExecutor1;
    callback2: CallbackExecutor2;
    callback3: CallbackExecutor3(fb_reference := _myfb);
    _fb: FB(callback1 := callback1, callback2 := callback2, callback3 := callback3);
END_VAR
END_PROGRAM
```

Note: Creating 'throwaway' FunctionBlocks just for the sake of passing callbacks is not free, if you are working in an environment with limited resources I'd recommend avoiding this method. Also, passing arguments to those callbacks is even more difficult, if not impossible (in a generic way at least).

Or return a boolean for every callback and check them on the callers side. For the second option, we can look at the TON FunctionBlock from the STANDARD library:

```pascal
VAR
    timer: TON;
END_VAR

timer(IN := TRUE; PT := T#5S); // 5 second timer

IF (timer.Q) THEN
    // executed when the timer counts 5 seconds
END_IF
```

In your case, maybe something like this:

```pascal
VAR
    obj: MyPOU;
END_VAR

obj( (* inputs *) );

IF (obj.callback1) THEN
    Func1();
END_IF

IF (obj.callback2) THEN
    Func2();
END_IF
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is [interfaces](https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.14.0/en/_cds_obj_interface/) in CODESYS 3, which are basically method-pointers. You simply make sure that you add a reference to the interface that you want to be called either:

1. When you create the instance of FB_Alarm (through [FB_Init](https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.12.0/en/_cds_method_fb_init_fb_reinit/)) **OR**
2. As an input to the function block.

Comment: Interfaces can indeed help in achieving similar results. This is the alternative I mention in my question. (e.g. injecting an `IAlarmEventHandler` into Alarm and implementing it in a calling FB).

````
public interface IAlarmEventHandler
{
    public void HandleAlarmEvent(ref Alarm alarm, AlarmEvent event);
}
````
But I would like to know whether the proposed 'method-injection' is possible.